VPN туннель в локальную сеть
Как настроить доступ к FTP с серым ip из интернета?
Имеем:

Микротик с серым ip. В сети крутится FTP сервер.
VPS сервер с поднятым WireGuard Easy

Т.е. к примеру есть у меня домен ftp.mywebsite.com как сделать проброс до локальной сети.

Схему полнял так: VPS[ DNAT->ipsrv ] ---- mikrotik[ ipprov -- VPN,ip_rule -- iplan ] ----- SRV[ ipsrv ]. В мироктике трфик от VPS надо маркировать и пропускать по дополнительной таблице маршрутизации в которой default gw будет адрес vps в vpn-туннеле.

Поднимаете на микротике клиент к VPN, Прописываете адреса и правила маскарад в NAT.
После подключаетесь к ftp по внутреннему адресу сети VPN.
